# Why iterating list gives me stackoverflow error?

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I am getting Stackoverflow whenever below code is ran. I am not able to understand why this is happening? And how we can fix it?

```
  public boolean compare(List<Task> source, List<Task> actual) {
    return compareTasks(source, actual) && compare(actual, source);
  }

  public boolean compareTasks(List<Task> source, List<Task> actual) {
    matchList = new ArrayList<Task>();
    differList = new ArrayList<Task>();
    for (Task task : actual) {
      if (source.contains(task)) {
        matchList.add(task);
      } else {
        differList.add(task);
      }
    }
    return (differList.size() == 0) ? true : false;
  }
```

Below is the error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
    at com.user.test.Task.getKey(Task.java:209)
    at com.user.test.Task.equals(Task.java:220)
    at java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(ArrayList.java:216)
    at java.util.ArrayList.contains(ArrayList.java:199)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1000)
```

Comment: Minor suggestion: if you ever find yourself writing `blah ? true : false`, just use `blah`. There's no need to write "true if blah is true, false if it's false." So in your method, just `return differLists.size() == 0`. (Similarly, instead of `blah ? false : true`, just do `!blah`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the issue is in here:

```
public boolean compare(List<Task> source, List<Task> actual) {
   return compareTasks(source, actual) && compare(actual, source);
}
```

Imagine you want to compare list A to list B. If you'll notice:

- Calling compare(A, B) calls compare(B, A).
- Calling compare(B, A) calls compare(A, B).
- Calling compare(A, B) calls compare(B, A).
- Calling compare(B, A) calls compare(A, B).
- Calling compare(A, B) calls compare(B, A).
- Calling compare(B, A) calls compare(A, B).
- Calling compare(A, B) calls compare(B, A).
- Calling compare(B, A) calls compare(A, B).
- etc.

This recursion never terminates, so it eventually triggers a stack overflow.

To fix this issue, consider rewriting this as

```
public boolean compare(List<Task> source, List<Task> actual) {
   return compareTasks(source, actual) && compareTasks(actual, source); // call compareTasks, not compare.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling compareTasks again in the method. Change it to the following line:
`return compareTasksList(source, actual) && compareTasksList(actual, source);`